# how to create interactive tooltip in ag grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want to add links to a custom tooltip component in AG-grid, but the tooltip disappears before I can click it. See example
[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/w4YX2fQRClCyKjjf?open=index.jsx)

The documentation did not provide a solution

Custom Tooltip:

```js
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';

export default (props) => {
  const data = useMemo(
    () => props.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(props.rowIndex).data,
    []
  );

  return (
    <div
      className="custom-tooltip"
      style={{ backgroundColor: props.color || 'white' }}
    >
      <p>
        <span>{data.athlete}</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <span>Country: </span> {data.country}
      </p>
      <div>
        <a href="https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-tooltip/">
        ag grid component tooltip
      </a>
      </div>
      
      <p>
        <span>Total: </span> {data.total}
      </p>
    
    </div>
  );
};
```